# running pip opens javascript file

Tags: python-3.x, pip

whenever I run something with pip in console on windows 10, it opens the javascript file 'cli.js'. i added python to my environment variables. python runs fine in console.

and yes this all this was run in cmd + admin or powershell.

Anybody that has an idea?

Comment: Until someone pops up with an explanation you could simply try finding cli.js on your drives. Its surroundings and/or something in its header may give away what it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue because i had the npm module pip installed, removing this fixed my issue

remove with npm uninstall pip